# TeX compiler with written privacy policy

Tags: installing, documentation, tex-general, software, privacy

I have a weird question: I am working at a public high school in New Hampshire, and I can't have any software installed on my school laptop unless the tech office determines that it does not violate various data protection rules. One step is for them to read the privacy policy.
Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there a TeX compiler with a written privacy policy that might pass muster?
I have tried explaining that the software (except auto updates) runs entirely offline, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: more accessibility than privacy but a vpat statement from tug is at https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/attachments/20210323/39601786/attachment-0001.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiao52rhIL6AhVBoVwKHeN3CnUQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0puJTtXxBlis0T9nefUeg8